# EmguCV: Detect a ball in the frame

Tags: computer-vision, opencv, edge-detection

I am having a VERY hard time capturing when the ball comes into frame in this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1V6_OHrXIo

I have no idea what to set the parameters too, and trying random values doesn't seem to help at all, I can't see the pattern to know what effect the numbers are having.  This is what I'm attempting.

Background subtraction, or color detection won't work, as they could easily change.  I need a more generalized solution.

```
var laneSixBedRect = new Rectangle(new Point(240, 185), new Size(240, 150));
var laneSixBed = imgSource.GetSubRect(laneSixBedRect);

TrackShot(laneSixBed);

private static void TrackShot(Image<Bgr, byte> laneBed)
{
    var laneBedGray = laneBed.Convert<Gray, byte>();

    var circles = laneBedGray.HoughCircles(
        new Gray(150),  //cannyThreshold
        new Gray(75),   //circleAccumulatorThreshold
        2.0,            //Resolution of the accumulator used to detect centers of the circles
        20.0,           //min distance 
        5,              //min radius
        50              //max radius
        )[0];           //Get the circles from the first channel

    foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
        laneBed.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Brown), 2);
}
```

**Edit:** This is my currentTrackShot method, it's running about 70% as far as accuracy, still some false positives, and some missed positives.

```
    private static void TrackShot(Rectangle laneRect, Image<Bgr, byte> prevImage, Image<Bgr, byte> currImage, Image<Bgr, byte> background)
    {
        var laneBedBack = background.GetSubRect(laneRect);
        var laneBedPrev = prevImage.GetSubRect(laneRect);
        var laneBedCurr = currImage.GetSubRect(laneRect);

        var laneBedBackGray = laneBedBack.Convert<Gray, byte>();
        //TODO: Should these be Smoothed?
        var laneBedPrevGray = laneBedPrev.Convert<Gray, byte>().SmoothGaussian(5);
        var laneBedCurrGray = laneBedCurr.Convert<Gray, byte>().SmoothGaussian(5);

        //TODO: Uncomment to see difference between frames, nearly black when no motion
        //var diff = laneBedPrevGray.AbsDiff(laneBedCurrGray);
        //diff.Convert<Bgr, byte>().CopyTo(laneBedCurr);

        //TODO: Improve these values
        var prevFeatures = laneBedPrevGray.GoodFeaturesToTrack(100, .01, .1, 3)[0];

        var returnFeatures = new PointF[1];
        byte[] status;
        float[] trackError;
        OpticalFlow.PyrLK(laneBedPrevGray, laneBedCurrGray, prevFeatures, new Size(15, 15), 5, new MCvTermCriteria(5), out returnFeatures, out status, out trackError);

        //TODO: Now how do I refine this???
        for (var i = 0; i < returnFeatures.Length; i++)
        {
            var prevPoint = prevFeatures[i];
            var currPoint = returnFeatures[i];
            var state = status[i];
            var error = trackError[i];

            var line = new LineSegment2D(new Point((int)prevPoint.X, (int)prevPoint.Y), new Point((int)currPoint.X, (int)currPoint.Y));
            if (state == 1 && line.Length > 15 && error < 10)
            {
                laneBedCurr.Draw(line, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
                Console.WriteLine("E: {0}", error);
                Console.WriteLine("L: {0}", line.Length);
            }
        }

        viewerModified.Image = currImage;
    }
```

**EDIT2:** My ulimate goal is to be able to draw a line along the trajectory the ball took and store that trajectory in some fashion that can be compared to others.

Answer (score 4):

### Remove things you don't want

Since the camera is static, you might want to use a background remover first. I found that the standard one provided with OpenCV works pretty well. I create it like this in the Android OpenCV SDK (you can play with the parameters) :

```
backgroundSubtractor = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG(3, 4, 0.8);
```

Then, apply it to each image in your video (no need to re-instantiate it unless you move the camera, it will learn from the sequence of images).

### Computing the motion

First, using the Hough Transform for fast-moving shapes isn't very useful. The Hough transform requires you to be able to detect the shape's boundary with some accuracy, which obviously you can't, thanks to the motion blur.

I would suggest looking into algorithms for computing the optical flow. I don't know how close EmguCV is to the original OpenCV, but you could try `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` (computes the flow for a set of points in the image, usually obtained using the `goodFeaturesToTrack` method) or `calcOpticalFlowFarneback` (computes a dense flow for the whole image, but more CPU-hungry).

Additionally, there have been some people working on CUDA/GLSL versions of Lucas-Kanade (the first one) if you really want to have a fast, dense flow algorithm, but I haven't seen a lot of useful implementations.

See the OpenCV documentation here : http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcOpticalFlowPyrLK

Comment: EmguCV is just a C# wrapper for OpenCV, it seems to have most everything covered.

Comment: Then you're probably okay with that! Does your camera move, or is it static? It's much, much easier for the latter!

Comment: It will be static.  However, there could be other things moving in the image.  But that's a problem for later.  Right now I just want to detect the motion of a ball moving in the frame.

Comment: See updated answer then, you might want to use the background removed included in OpenCV before doing any work!

Comment: Since the camera is static, you should be able to leverage prior knowledge, such as the fact that the balls only move through fixed planes, namely the alley.

Comment: Good point @Maurits! The thing is, try to eliminate everything you can : background, wrong trajectories, wrong sizes, wrong shapes...

Comment: I'm going to have to rearchitect some things, as presently, I was checking each frame individually, and losing context.  I had managed to get it partially working with background subtraction and Hough, but it was only about 70% reliable.  Thanks for the help so far, I'll be attempting to integrate your help in a few hours, and see what happens!

Comment: @F.X. I can't seem to find parameters to pass to GoodFeaturesToTrack that result in ANY results.   No points are found.

Comment: I got 10 features, with the parameters, .1 quality, .1 minDistance, 3 blocksize.  I plot them on the screen.  And don't see how this will work.  They rarely seem to mark the ball.

Comment: @F.X. my edit to the original post has the latest code, I'm getting lots of motion, lots because of light changes, now I need to figure out how to ensure it's the ball causing it, not light shifts.

Comment: Traditionally, you might want to filter against the trajectory of the ball. I haven't yet thought about it, but I'm pretty sure there are ways to remove noise (i.e. seemingly random moves) predicted by the optical flow. Also, pay attention to the output in the `status` matrix. The results of the optical flow are only valid when the corresponding value in this matrix is `true` (or `255`, or `>0`).

Comment: @F.X. I am checking state, and only using the record when it's value is 1 (true).  I'm intrigued about the rest of what you said, but this is all way over my head.  I'm typically a line of business programmer, I have never taken the math courses required for signal processing.  I sort of understand the basics, but I can't even read the formulas as half the symbols I have no clue the meaning of them.  I was thinking that I only want to track motion that's "foward-ish" (very technical terminology)  And I need to work the BackgroundSubtractorMOG into this

Comment: If that's not anything classified, secret or personal, why do you want to find the location of the ball? Things could be different if you're only looking for the speed, compared to what it would be like if you were looking for its exact position! Not knowing about image processing is fine, intuition is what you need most of the time ;)

Comment: @F.X. Well, the ultimate project is kind of secret still.  However, I can say that first, I just need to know that a ball was thrown, with as close to 100% accuracy as I can get (false positives, and missed shots are not at all ideal).  Later on, I'd love to be able to track and superimpose the path the ball took down the lane.

Comment: @CaffGeek : Do you have examples (images) of the outputs of the background remover/optical flow algorithms? I don't know how much the lighting changes affects their outputs, but you can usually see if it's a good idea to keep on using them, just by looking at the images!

Comment: @F.X. I'll create a video of the backgroundmask created using BackgroundSubtractorMOG, and try to post it up tonight.

Comment: @CaffGeek: How is it going now? I have been doing the exact same thing with a tennis ball for the last few weeks, and I'm starting to get some very good results, so if you're still interested I can always update the answer!

Comment: @F.X. I'm still interested, just got busy, and haven't had a chance to revisit the problem.